# how to remove '-' symbol after using sef_title()

Tags: codeigniter

```
$city = sef_title($city);

 redirect('/hotels/lis_t/'.$state_id .'/'.$city.'/');
```

1)I use `sef_title($city);` for when this url is passed if the cityname has space,the space is replaced by this symbol `-`.
2)But after passing this url i can not read the city name from table,because
if the cityname is `$city=himachal` pradesh

after using `sef_title($city)` result is himachal-pradesh
3)But this name  is not in table because table contain  himachal pradesh.
4)So how to remove the `-` symbol after url passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str_replace in the controller: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$city = str_replace('-', ' ', $city);
```

Answer (score 0):

i personally suggests to re format database table,
which can be like : 
state_id , state_name , state_permalink
and state_id = 1
state_name = "Himachal Pradesh"
state_permalink = "himachal_pradesh"

because if, you replace the char '-', you can not bring it back. !

Comment: i get the result :-)$city = str_replace('-', ' ', $city);

Comment: obviously, you will get the result.
but thinking globally,
when there is actually having '-' in the city name, you can not differentiate.

Comment: '-' symbol given to the cityname in the place of space. with the help of sef_title().sef_title($city)